# TightVNC on VS2015 compile from source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, tightvnc

I am trying to compile the [TightVNC](https://tightvnc.com/download.php) from the source code.

Here is my system details:

- Windows 10
- SDK 8.1

When i build the project it throw error about the folder or file not found. I try to install and include the files but it won't worked.

sidenote: I am not a C++ developer, i have to compile it from source code.

[image: TightVNC Error while building from soruce]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://tightvnc.com/doc/win32/building.txt <- they have instructions for VS 2008 and 2010. Building on 2015 doesn't seem to be directly supported. If you have used the `tightvnc2010.sln` file and it doesn't work for you, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Please don't put the error messages as an image, images are not searchable and not usable for people with vision problems.

Comment: *sidenote: I am not a C++ developer* -- And if there are bugs after the build, who are you going to call to fix / diagnose the issues?  Authors who give the option to compile the source assume that you are competent in C++ and your build system.

Comment: add **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um** to your header search

Comment: @jakub_d  https://tightvnc.com/whatsnew.php  <-- from TightVNC 2.8.11 they migrated to the vs2015. so it should work on vs2015. It is throwing the error message about libraries are not found. The above issues are because of some libs missings.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i will try it and update you on this.

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

The error

`RC1015 can't open include file afxres.h`

seems to generate from project because it requires the header file from MFC. As far as I understand, visual studio 2015 default setup does not install Visual C++ MFC package. Therefore you need to modify the Visual Studio 2015 setup and add the MFC.

**Please close VS2015 and Go To**

```
Control Panel->Programs and Features->

Microsoft Visual Studio <Professional/Enterprise>->

Change->Modify->Add Microsoft Foundation Classes
```

[image]

Then re-open visual studio 2015 and re-build the solution.